# PHP PDO почему идет преобразование текста в binary?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Я использую PHP PDO:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE item SET description = :desc WHERE id = :item_id");
$statement->execute([':desc' => 'Текст на русском и английском с элементами html большой длины (mediumText)', ':item_id' => 26]);
```

При выполнении данного запроса происходит ошибка: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x81<sup>...' for column 'description' at row 3`. В логах запроса я обнаружил что по какой-то причине данные уже передаются в таком виде: `{":item_id":26, ":desc":"(binary value)"}`, т.е. непонятно почему описание становится binary value, именно поэтому и происходит ошибка при выполнения запроса, т.к. в бд поле имеет тип данных MediumText, и binary принимать не может. Как это можно исправить?

P.S. При вставке данных напрямую в бд, без PDO, все работает.

Comment: Могу предположить, что кодировки таблицы (столбца) не совпадают с кодировкой передаваемых данных. Но это не точно

Answer (score 2):

Никакого "преобразования" в "binary" при выполнении запроса не происходит.

В сообщениях об ошибке / логах нестандартные символы кодируются для большей совместимости.

Comment: Но почему тогда возникает ошибка 1366 при выполнении запроса, ведь pdo по идеи просто экранирует кавычки в тексте, и именно через PDO происходит ошибка? В логах также обнаружил что все данные были в таком формате: `\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5\x3a\x3c\x2f\x70\x3e\x20\x3c\x70\x3e\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\x20\x28\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd1`......